# Function not being set correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a function that creates a new record in the database and returns the ID of the record created. From this I need to assign a function to a select with the value of the returned ID.

```
.done(function(response) {
       //console.log(siblings[1].dataset.contno);
       var dbResponse = JSON.parse(response);

         document.getElementById(runID).setAttribute('data-runid', dbResponse.id);

       var newRunID = dbResponse.id;
       var driverSelectID='driverSelectRun'+runCode;
       //adding the onchange function with the correct ID to the dropdowns (the assignVehicle FUnction takes the runID which is unknown untill response)
       (function(newRunID) {
         document.getElementById(driverSelectID).onchange = function () {
            assignDriver(newRunID);
         }
         })(newRunID);
        (function(newRunID) {
         document.getElementById(vehicleSelectID).onchange = function () {
            assignVehicle(newRunID);
         }
        })(newRunID);

       console.log(newRunID);
    });
```

The console.log for the newRunID is 1566 but the onchange function of this select does not contain the new run id it simply shows as assignVehicle(newRunID) instead of actually using the value returned from the database (assignVehicle(1566)). I have used the exact same method on another part of the code which works fine. Can anyone see why this is not working correctly.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

```
<select id="driverSelectRun6">...</select>
```

That is the code for the select. It is definately being targeted correctly as the function is being set just without the arguement.

**UPDATE**
This was a scope issue. The newRunID was declared using var newRunID= but this was delcared in the .done function so was of local scope instead of global. removing the var to make it just newRunID= worked  because assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object)

Comment: So what is the element you are attaching the change event to? We need to see some HTML. What is `document.getElementById('vehicleSelectRun'+runCode` referencing?

Comment: You probably want to use an arrow function so that the scope of the callback has the correct newRunId in it already. Then, drop the argument to the arrow function like epascarello suggested. I think that should do it...

Comment: What prints out if you do console.log(newRunID); inside that onchange function?

Comment: i have added the code fore the select above the id for the driver and the vechicle are thesame baring the prefix

Comment: and @Chayemor the output of that console.log is 1566 which is the correct id i want to pass to the function

Comment: Interesting. I'm inclined to think the function itself, assignVehicle() might be what's wrong. Could you post that? There should be no reason for the console.log to be able to see the value of the variable but assignVehicle does not.

Comment: I just moved the console.log(newRunID) to just before the assignVehicle() function as suggested by @NisFan and it does not output anything. it will output only outside of the function to create the onchange

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are redefining the variable newRunID as an argument and that argument is actually the event object that is returned from the change event listener.

```
.onchange = function (newRunID) {
```

should be

```
.onchange = function () {
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but i had it like that before and was the same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
(function(newRunID) {
      document.getElementById(driverSelectID).onchange = function () {
         assignDriver(newRunID);
      }
})(newRunID);
```

Comment: Im not sure if this will work as i do not know the ID until i get the response from the record creation.

Comment: Have just tried it and the function is still showing as function({assignDriver(newRunID)}

Comment: Put console.log(newRunID) before assignDriver(newRunID);

Comment: There is no output in the console when i put it there Am so confused!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181295/discussion-between-akaust-and-nisfan).